# How to implement real time notification with springboot and react js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, websocket

i want to see real time notifications in the front reactjs  when i add an entity in the back so i did this in springboot [websocketconfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz0g0.png) and a component that handles the notification [TagSocket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FAoR.png) and this is how i call it in the service when adding a tag  [tagadd function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhmkj.png)and tried this code in reactjs [Reactjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQpal.png)  but i always get  this error message in the console [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4lr9.png).How can i fix this issue